# Unused columns in a view / subquery (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

If the result set of a query does not use a field produced by a subquery or view, is that field still processed by the subquery? I have a lot of views in my database that are used in many places, but the exact set of fields needed varies by context. Rather than duplicating similar queries in each context (with the appropriate field group), I've been using views that may contain extra fields for each context. It looks like these extra views do affect performance in MySQL (I experience a 1/4 improvement in performance by removing the extra field in the example below). Any solutions? Different database (i.e. Oracle)?

See below for an example; the charge_off_date field could clearly be skipped when running the view, but it still affects performance.

```
select 
    l.loan_id, last_payment_date
from
    loans as l
        left join
    (select 
        loan_id,
            max(ph.received_d) as last_payment_date,
            max(case
                when ph.co = 1 then coalesce(ph.received_d, ph.month)
                else null
            end) as charge_off_date
    from
        payment_history as ph) as payment_stats ON payment_stats.loan_id = l.loan_id
```

Comment: If somebody owes money is there any benefit for them to make a $1 payment and their last_payment_date being later?

Comment: Can we see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL instantiates (non-correlated) subqueries and creates an execution plan for views that is not optimized beyond the view.  In other words, MySQL will not optimize in this case.

Other databases are smarter about optimization.  That does not mean they will do the right thing, but there is a chance.

I would suggest, though, that you write the query as just a `join` with an aggregation and no subquery:

```
select l.loan_id, max(ph.received_d) as last_payment_date,
       max(case when ph.co = 1 then coalesce(ph.received_d, ph.month)
           end) as charge_off_date
from loans l left join
     payment_history ph
     on ph.loan_id = l.loan_id
group by l.loan_id;
```

There is no need for the subquery in the `from` clause (and this isn't allowed in a MySQL view anyway).  Plus, if you have a `where` clause, this should take advantage of the `where` clause and improve performance.

Comment: Thanks. My concern with that approach is twofold: first, that creates a chance for redundancy, since the calculated columns might need to be reused by other calculations. For instance, you could calculate days_since_chargeoff and loan_duration_until_chargeoff. These would all require redefining charge_off_date. Second, if any different tables need to use charge_off_date, there is no longer a single consistent calculation. Instead, they would need to join and recalculate for charge_off_date each time. So it seems like there is  a tradeoff between extra fields & redundant calculation/definition.

Comment: This approach is less general because with `SELECT #COLUMNS# FROM #VIEW# WHERE #CONDITIONS#` you are able to have the `#COLUMNS#` and `#CONDITIONS#` easily generated by your reporting application.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken - Promote your Comment to an Answer.

Comment: @RickJames . . . William put a bounty on the question.  I don't think he is trying to answer it.